# Dimensions of a distance time relation

Tags: kinematics, differentiation, dimensional-analysis, calculus

Recently I came accross a question which was:-
Suppose the velocity of a moving particle varies with time as 
$$v=50t^2.$$
And we have to find out the acceleration at $t = 10s.$
I know that I can use differentiation to calculate the acceleration at $t = 10s.$
But my question is that the relation 
$$v=50t^2$$ is not dimensionally correct because on RHS the dimensions of v are L/T but on the LHS the dimensions are T^2. So is this question right or wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right, that equation is dimensionally wrong. A better way to express that equation makes use of *quantity calculus* (see e.g. all the answers to [this question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/31375/16219) on Chemistry.SE and all the references reported in [this answer](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/28918/20058) of mine on Academia.SE).

The basic idea is that the coefficient "50" that appears in the equation should be treated as a quantity, and not as a pure number. Within this framework, that equation becomes

$$v = (50\,\mathrm{m/s^3})\,t^2$$

which is dimensionally correct.

And for those reluctant to write units within equations (some are), there is indeed the possibility of writing

$$v = kt^2$$

with $k = 50\,\mathrm{m/s^3}$.

Answer (score 0):

The question is not wrong, the $50$ is the value of some constant to make dimensions fit. So in this case, $50$ would have unit $ms^{-3}$

Comment: ...but you have to consider the units in your results--e.g., if it depends on $50^3$ you have 9 powers of 1/T to deal with--or you can guess the simplest form it can have:  $ a \propto (50 \,m/s^3)(10\,s)$.

Comment: The question *is* wrong because it does not specify in which untis the consant has the value 50. You've guessed $50 \,\mathrm{m/s}$, but how do you know it is not $50 \,\mathrm{miles/hour}$?